# Firebase saving auto generated id to it's collection when creating collection

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

```
  const handleSubmit = async() => {
    const productsRef = firestore.collection("Products").doc();
    try {
      setIsLoading(true);
      var array = await uploadToS3();
      productsRef.set({
      caption: captionInput.value,
      user: auth.currentUser.uid,
      timeStamp:time
      })
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    } finally{
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };
```

Here is my code.
When setting document to firebase, is there any ways that I can save my document's randomly generated id to the collection?

For example if my generated id is "hello world"

my collection has
caption:'blah blah'
timeStamp:'blah blah'
user: 'uid'
id: 'hello world'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you pre-create the ref to the new document, you can get the [`id` property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) from that reference:

```
productsRef.set({
  id: productsRef.id
  caption: captionInput.value,
  user: auth.currentUser.uid,
  timeStamp:time
})
```